# Using KinD to create a local cluster and the CPU maintains high usage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-mac, kind

I'm using [KinD](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) to create a local cluster and noted that the CPU percentage usage stays relatively high, between 40-60 for docker.hyperkit on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6. Within Docker for mac I limited the resources to CPUs: 4 and Memory:6.00 GB.

My KinD cluster consists of a control plane node and three worker nodes. Is this CPU usage normal for docker for mac? Can I check to see the utilization per container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each kind "node" is a Docker container, so you can inspect those in "normal" ways.

Try running `kind create cluster` to create a single-node cluster.  If you run `docker stats` you will get CPU, memory, and network utilization information; you can also get the same data through the Docker Desktop application, selecting (whale) > Dashboard.  This brings up some high-level statistics on the container.  Sitting idle on a freshly created cluster, this seems to be consistently using about 30% CPU for me.  (So 40-60% CPU for a control-plane node and three workers sounds believable.)

Similarly, since each "node" is a container, you can `docker exec -it kind-control-plane bash` to get an interactive debugging shell in a node container.  Once you're there, you can run `top` and similar diagnostic commands.  On my single node I see the top processes as `kube-apiserver` (10%), `kube-controller` (5%), `etcd` (5%), and `kubelet` (5%).  Again, that seems reasonably normal, though it might be nice if it used less CPU sitting idle.